# Fewer than 21 producers for custom EOS blockchain?

Tags: nodeos

Can one configure a custom EOS blockchain to require fewer than 21 producers, e.g. 3 or 10?  And if so, how?

I can't find anything in the various `*config.hpp*` source files like chain_config.hpp.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the launcher program. Look for the parameter named:

```
--pnodes
```

This is the parameter that determines the number of block producing nodes in your eosio compatible blockchain.

You should probably change other parameters there too so read the whole explanation here:

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/testnet.md#the-launcher-application